# using java to get ways from osm

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-2, java, geotools, overpass-api

I just try to figure out how to query all ways within a radius of let's say 1km from a defined point. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: select-region]

I've already read about overpass api, GeoTools and openlayers, and it all appears to be doing what I want it to do. But practically I still haven't figured out how to do it. I want to build an application using Java. So it would be great having a java-solution for querying the required data.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Same problem. Sucks your question was closed. Have you figured it out?